# Netty / Shiro Integration

Tags: http, netty, shiro

Instead of writing my own authentication handler, I'd like to use an existing authentication framework, e.g. Apache Shiro. After some research I have found that integrating Shiro with netty is not a straight forward task, although passing the Subject along the channel is not a problem, but rather setting up all the required handlers. Is there an existing integration (e.g. a ChannelHandler etc.) or at least a public sample that shows how to authenticate HTTP requests in netty with Shiro with the typical features (remember me, cookie store for subject etc.)?

Best regards and thanks in advance, Remigius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the lack of interest and support I chose to write my own authentication handler.